# Facebook Checkbox plugin remains hidden

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm implementing the Facebook Checkbox Plugin on a test page, as [per their documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin). However, the checkbox doesn't render. It remains hidden.

[You can test my page here](https://maartenbelmans.com/fbtest).

I came across a few other SO questions with the same issue but none of them seem to solve my problem. I made sure:

- that my domain is whitelisted in my FB app.
- the `user_ref` is always unique.
- I'm the owner of the app so I can test in development mode.
- I'm logged into my FB account.

Below is my code:

```
<?php $random_val=rand(100000,999999).rand(100000,999999).rand(100000,999999);?>

<html>
<head>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '472807186447994',
            xfbml      : true,
            cookie     : true,
            version    : 'v2.6'
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('messenger_checkbox', function(e) {
            console.log(e);

            if (e.event == 'rendered') {
                console.log("Plugin was rendered");
            } else if (e.event == 'checkbox') {
                var checkboxState = e.state;
                console.log("Checkbox state: " + checkboxState);
            } else if (e.event == 'not_you') {
                console.log("User clicked 'not you'");
            } else if (e.event == 'hidden') {
                console.log("Plugin was hidden");
            }
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
    );

    function confirmOptIn() {
        FB.AppEvents.logEvent('MessengerCheckboxUserConfirmation', null, {
            'app_id':'472807186447994',
            'page_id':'408145106012959',
            'ref':'some-ref-here',
            'user_ref':'<?php echo $random_val; ?>'
        });
    }
</script>      

<div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="fb-messenger-checkbox"  
        origin="https://maartenbelmans.com/fbtest"
        page_id="408145106012959"
        messenger_app_id="472807186447994"
        user_ref="<?php echo $random_val; ?>" 
        prechecked="false" 
        allow_login="true" 
        size="large">
    </div>   
</div>

<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="confirmOptIn()" value="Confirm Opt-in"/>
</body>
```

I'm unsure of what to do to troubleshoot this. **Any ideas?**

Comment: Have you whitelisted your domain in your Messenger Profile?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/domain-whitelisting

Comment: @amuramoto yes, I did. See point one on my list :-)

Answer (score 1):

As I seen all of the Fb Policy you have been passed, But One thing you missed over there As I seen your code structure, you put the facebook DIV outside the body section of the html that is wrong.

Ref.: http://pasted.co/b052c12f

```
    <div class="fb-messenger-checkbox"  
       origin="https://maartenbelmans.com/fbtest"
       page_id="408145106012959"
       messenger_app_id="472807186447994"
       user_ref="<?php echo $random_val; ?>" 
       prechecked="false" 
       allow_login="true" 
      size="large">
   </div>
```

This above div must be inside the body of the any page.

So, your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting origin="maartenbelmans.com/" in the div? Origin should only be the domain, so right now when the plugin is checking your origin against the whitelist there isn't a match.

Answer (score 0):

I once came across these issues
One was whitelisting domain
One was the origin thing

The other was when i was playing around wirh the version please be sure version you choose as 2.8 is out also, so the 2.6 may not really be it, please find out the corresponding version you are working on

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this.

Troubleshooting Tips

If you're having trouble getting the plugin to properly render, try the tips below:

1. Verify that your bot is actually approved for the pages_messaging permission.
2. Verify that your page has webhook subscription to your bot.
3. If you see a console error like "Refused to display *** in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: ***", check that the domain of the page the plugin is being rendered on has been whitelisted.
4. If the allow_login parameter is set to false, you will need to have a valid Facebook user session (i.e. not logged in) otherwise the plugin will be hidden.
5. Testing on localhost is not supported right now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is tips from facebook:

1. Verify that your bot is actually approved for the pages_messaging permission.
2. Verify that your page has webhook subscription to your bot.
3. If you see a console error like "Refused to display in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive:", check that the domain of the page the plugin is being rendered on has been whitelisted.
4. If the allow_login parameter is set to false, you will need to have a valid Facebook user session (i.e. not logged in) otherwise the plugin will be hidden.
5. Testing on localhost is not supported right now.
6. Set xfbml to true in only one place. Either set it to true in FB.init OR set it in the SDK url like so https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1.

I follow all of this tips, but it still didn't worked.

My solution was to add WebHook url and subscribe to **messaging events**